# Spring boot : Override property value reader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configurationproperty

I am using Spring's `@PropertySource` and `@ConfigurationProperties` to read the properties from a file. Below are the sample properties:

```
patterns[0]=\b(test1)\b
patterns[1]=\b(test2)\b
```

Below is the class that reads these properties:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:patterns.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class PatternConfig {

    private List<String> patterns;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

This reads the properties as expected and sets the values in `patterns` list. However, what I really want to do is, to compile the `pattern` before it gets added and then add it into the list of Patterns. E.g. the new list will be

```
private List<Pattern> patterns;
```

So, I need to override *something* which would call `Pattern.compile` on string property and return `Pattern` object which would then get added into the list. Is it possible?

Comment: IMHO you don't need to override it (maybe also shouldn't), you can just define it as string, and compute it in getter..

Comment: Have you tried it...

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in this configuration that returns the list of patterns, annotate it with @Bean, and do the pattern compile within the method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Import(PatternConfig.class)
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}


@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:patterns.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
class PatternConfig {


  public void setPatterns(List<String> patterns) {
      this.patterns = patterns;
  }

  private List<String> patterns;

  public List<String> getPatterns() {
      return patterns;
  }

  @Bean
  public List<Pattern> compiledPatterns() {

      List<Pattern> compiledPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
      for (String pattern : patterns) {
        compiledPatterns.add(
                Pattern.compile(pattern));
      }
      return compiledPatterns;
  }

}
```

Comment: This would mean I need to read the entire list in string and then convert it by iterating through it again (once at least). Can we somehow perform this conversion when properties get added into the list?

Comment: Isn't that going to achieve exactly the same thing though ?

Comment: Could you add an example to the answer?

Comment: Code example added